# Конвертация python в exe

Tags: python, pyinstaller

При конвертации через pyinstaller exe мелькает командная строка и больше ничего не происходит.

В моем проекте присутствует графический интерфейс и все, что я нашел, это то, что необходим другой подход, но что конкретно делать мне неизвестно, руководство pyinstaller уж слишком громоздкое, есть быстрые способы решения проблемы?

Comment: Нужно понять что PyIntaller собирает архив с пайтном и главным скриптом, потом на другой машине его распаковывает во временную папку, в стандартную упаковку входит интепретатор со всеми необходимыми файлами и главный ваш скрипт, всё остальное вам нужно ручками добавлять. То что выходит консоль и тут же закрывается это нормально, вам сообщают об ошибке, то есть не найдены файлы, которые вы используете в скрипте но не добавили в упаковку.

Comment: Быстрого решения нет. Причин может быть куча разных. Запускайте программу сразу из консоли, чтобы увидеть какие ошибки выдает, дальше уже решаете возникшие ошибки.

Answer (score 1):

Если мелькает командная строка, то тут можно посоветовать запускать файл из самой командной строки. Для этого можно в папке зажать Shift+ПКМ и вызвать PowerShell. Там вводите название файла, жмёте Enter. В этом случае командная строка сама не закроется и будет видна причина ошибки.